# 'IF' statement doesn't work right?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

When I print out the integers (1 or 0), all the iterations (there are 3 of them in this case) print out the correct number. First and the second one return 1, the last one returns zero. BUT, 'if' statement seems to display everything in it anyway. What am I doing wrong?

All the code below is inside a bigger 'for' loop.

```
$yn = 0;

if(!in_array($pos, $blocks)){
    $blocks[$x] = $pos;
    $x++;
    $yn = 1;
}
print_r($blocks);

print "YN: ".$yn; # this prints out 1, 1 and 0 on the last iteration

if(yn){
        # show some stuff (is displayed in all three iterations, but it shouldn't be on the last)
}
```

Comment: You forgot $ sign at if ($yn)

Comment: make sure that you don't have syntax errors before posting and saying that something "doesn't work right"

Comment: thanks, blind as hell I am ..

Comment: @haynar it wasn't a syntax error btw ..

Comment: @user1524316 no it isn't, it's a [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBKAC#Acronyms_and_other_names_for_a_user_error) :-)

Comment: @haynar Actually, it would yield _"Notice: Use of undefined constant yn - assumed 'yn'"_, but your point stands that one should first check for any errors/notices.

Comment: true indeed .. happens after a long seat in the chair sometimes:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
if($yn){
```

PHP is interpreting `yn` as a string, rather than as the variable you should be using.

Comment: ohh, I totally overlooked that! thanks!